# PHP/Javascript/AJAX - Redirect page with a form, and then submit it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've been making a webpage that gathers tweets depending on what you input on a form and I'm having some problems using the default form submit.

I want to change how the form submit works as it might take ages for the page to redirect and give the user a token id, due to a php script executing.
To make things simple I thought that the best way to make it faster is by redirecting and then submitting the form. Unfortunately I don't think you can do that with PHP.

Someone recommended me to give a look at AJAX, but I didn't get how that could help me.

This is how my form looks like:

```
<form action="testing.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="All of these words" autofocus/><br>
    <input type="text" name="search2" value="" placeholder="This exact word or phrase" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="search3" value="" placeholder="Any of these words" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="search4" value="" placeholder="None of these words" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="count" value="" placeholder="Number of tweets to search" />

    <select name="lang">
        <option value="">- Tweets language -</option>
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="es">Spanish(Español)</option>
    </select>

    <select name="region">
        <option value="">- Choose a Region -</option>
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="africa">Africa</option>
        <option value="namerica">North America</option>
        <option value="samerica">South America</option>
        <option value="asia">Asia</option>
        <option value="europe">Europe</option>
        <option value="oceania">Oceania</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="special" />
</form>
```

Comment: So you're asking for a tutorial on how to use Ajax? This site isn't for tutorials. StackOverflow is for programmed to display source code with a problem (a specific problem) and others help debug and fix it. Nothing to fix here... You will have more chance of people helping you if you make an attempt to use ajax. Any problems after that, i'm sure people will be happy to help.

Comment: If you go to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic you will se I'm not breaking any rules by asking this. This is a problem for me as I can't implement it, I've tried and failed. I don't necessarily need a code completed, any help is welcome.

Comment: Displaying your attempt(s) is a good start, we can look at your attempt(s) and explain to you why it didn't work and then offer solution(s).

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is the best way to do it.

If you don't know how to use AJAX, you can try setting action value to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and on the same page put your PHP code like this:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
   //phpcode
  }

?>

 //form code
```

This is one way to do it. Or you can read about AJAX and then implement that.

Comment: I've done it this way, but it take ages for the page to redirect, what I tried doing is redirecting and then submiting my form, instead of waiting untill the script finish executing, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: If your PHP code is too long, then even an AJAX script will take too long to return a response. If your script execution time is long, you'll have to run the time consuming script in the background. What exactly is your PHP code doing?

Comment: My php script gather up to 18000 tweets, that is why it takes a good amount of time.

Comment: That is a very intensive process, I think background processing is the right way to do it. 
You can make use of `popen()` to execute another script in the background and update the log after every 200 tweets fetched, then on your main page, you can display a percentage by reading this log, when it reaches 100%, you can then either redirect to the new page or use AJAX to fetch the content from this new page which generated all the tweets.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the solution to your problem is not AJAX.

From what I gather you're trying to allow a user to search tweets and see the results of their search.

It is simply impossible to see the results before the script that gathers results is done gathering them. The solution to your problem lies in a better method of searching.

Comment: Unfortunately it only refresh the page with GET method, but thanks anyways.

Comment: What about redirecting and then executing the script on the redirected page? Would that work?

Comment: Not if you're trying to display the results of a search through tweets. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: No, I store them in a sql table and then give the option to download it later.

Comment: But are you giving them the option to view it immediately too? Is this in a web browser? What's the page you want to direct them to after they submit the form (not the page you want to process the form with, the one that has whatever you want them to see after they submit the form)?

Comment: They can't see it immediatly. It is ran in a web browser and I want to redirect them to a page that will give them a key that will let them access the data later.